# Prove that if $n\geq\text{lcm}(a,b)$ and $\gcd(a,b)|n$ then $n=xa+yb$ for some integers $x,y\geq 0$

Tags: number-theory

I thought I had it, but then I realized I didn't. Even just a hint—am I going in the right direction or should I try something completely different?

We know that $\gcd(a,b)=wa+zb$ for some integers $w,z$. Then since $\gcd(a,b)|n$ we have that $k \gcd(a,b) = n$ for some integer $k$. Then $n=kwa+kzb$, so letting $x=kw$ and $b=kz$ gives the result.

Except that it doesn't because I realized that there's no promises about $kw$ and $kz$ being nonnegative and in fact I think that in general they are not.

I think there must be some way to reconcile this using $n\geq\text{lcm}(a,b)$ but I am not sure how to. Or maybe this argument was doomed from the start. Anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If $n=xa + yb$, then $n=(x-b)a + (y+a)b$.

If you start with $x>0$ and $y<0$, you can keep applying this hint repeatedly, until $y$ becomes positive. Of course, $x$ will keep decreasing at the same time... but can it become negative before $y$ jumps above zero?

Comment: I'm still rather stuck. I can't quite see how I can show that the coefficients are nonnegative from that. Can you possibly offer any other insight?

Comment: The hint has been expanded a bit, let's see if it helps!